# JS: Trying to test for a very specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a string for given specifications:

```
const string = 'd(iig(i)), d(iitm), d' // is valid
```

Mainly the string represents one or multiple blocks of `d`, which can be without brackets or empty brackets.
Each block is separated by comma and an optional space.

Inside of this block there can be g, i, t or m. Only g can optionaly open new bracket.

I started with this regex:

```
if (!/^[dgitm, ()]*$/.test(string)) {
  throw Error('Pattern has invalid character')
}
```

But I don't know how to treat these specifications:

1. Each block has to be separated by a comma (optinal with space)
2. Space is only allowed (optional) between d-blocks
3. d and g could have following brackets; i, t and m should not have following brackets
4. d is never inside any bracket

*Valid*

```
dd(ii)
d(i),d(g)
d(g(iig))
d(g(iig(i)))
```

*Invalid*

```
d(g(d))    // no nested d
d(x)       // invalid character
d(i())     // no brackets for i (only d or g)
d(ii)d(ii) // missing comma
i          // missing first level d
```

---

**Update**

Removed the spec for balanced brackets, as this can't be tested by regEx.

Comment: It will be helpful if you add more valid & invalid samples in question.

Comment: You might want to try jison.js for this instead of regular expressions.

Comment: You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/3103891) use regex to validate brackets

Comment: can a `g` appear within a `g(...)` bracket? If so, regex can't solve this.

Comment: Other than the brackets check, this regex satisfies all of your conditions: `/^(d\(?([itm]+|g\(?|\))*(, )?)+$/g`

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks for that. Rule 4 is missing: `d(g(d))` should be invalid.

Comment: [If it were PHP/PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/1qMmCJ/1)...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunatly I need the regex for JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^d+(\((g\(|[git](?!\()|\))+)*(,d+(\((g\(|[git](?!\()|\))+)*)*$
```

It can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/YVx7WZ/8).

**Explanation:**

```
^d+                                 The input must start with some 'd's (m>=1 times)

// First parenthesis' content:
(\((g\(|[git](?!\()|\))+)*          The following can appear n>=0 times:
                                    '(', then the following can appear p>=1 times:
                                        'g', then one of the following:
                                            - 'g('
                                            - ')'
                                            - 'g'/'i'/'t' - without a '(' after them
                                              (using negative lookahead)

// Every other element (optional):
(,d+(\((g\(|[git](?!\()|\))+)*)*    Starts with a ',d', ',dd' or ',ddd', etc.
                                    then the same as the first parenthesis' content
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you can't validate brackets with regex. However you **can** either implement an existing algorithm for that, or get a sense of initial validation by comparing the amount of opening and closing parenthesis (which obviously should be equal).

EDIT: Thank you, @anubhava, for the correction

Comment: It makes `d(i())` a valid input but as per OP it is not

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! I fixed it with a negative lookahead